# How to update the bindings inside a RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Picture a list of StackOverflow questions that can individually be upvoted and downvoted. Each one of them has a count that displays the number of its votes. Clicking on upvote increases that count by one, clicking on downvote decreases that count by one. That's the general idea of what I'm trying to achieve. The layout, `rv_item.xml` (condensed for brevity) for a single item in the RecyclerView:

```
data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.mycodez.Item"/>

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.mycodez.ListViewModel" />
</data>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/decrease_quantity"
    android:onClick="@{() -> vm.decrementItemQuantity(item)}"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:text="@{String.valueOf(item.quantity)}"
    tools:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/increase_quantity"
    android:onClick="@{() -> vm.incrementItemQuantity(item)}"/>
```

Where `@+id/decrease_quantity` is similar to a downvote, `@+id/quantity` similar to a vote count, and `@+id/increase_quantity` similar to an upvote. The adapter:

```
class ListRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListRvAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Item> items;
    private ListViewModel viewModel;
    private LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner;

    ListRvAdapter(List<Item> items, ListViewModel viewModel, LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        this.items = items;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        RvItemBinding binding = RvItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding, viewModel, lifecycleOwner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final RvItemBinding binding;
        private ListViewModel viewModel;
        private LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner;

        ViewHolder(RvItemBinding binding, ListViewModel viewModel, LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
            this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner;
        }

        public void bind(Item item) {
            binding.setItem(item);
            binding.setVm(viewModel);
            binding.executePendingBindings();
            binding.setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner);
        }
    }
}
```

I've omitted the ViewModel, `ListViewModel` because what `vm.decrementItemQuantity(item)` and `vm.incrementItemQuantity(item)` essentially do is call the model to update the quantity in the database:

```
@Query("UPDATE items SET quantity=quantity + 1 WHERE id=:itemId")
Completable incrementQuantity(int itemId);

@Query("UPDATE items SET quantity=quantity - 1 WHERE quantity > 1 AND id=:itemId")
Completable decrementQuantity(int itemId);
```

So while the quantity is being updated in the model, it's not clear to me how I should update the UI for that particular RecyclerView item to reflect that change. Normally, when using LiveData and DataBinding, I'd do something like `itemQuantityLiveData.setValue(item.quantity)` and that would immediately be reflected in the XML. But in this case, I'm using the `bind(Item item)` method in my ViewHolder, and the `item` object is being passed to the DataBinding layout as a variable, not as an expression.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Call `notifyPropertyChanged()` on your model. Don't forget to extend from `BaseObservable`.

Comment: Elaborate further. I'm already using LiveData. Are you suggesting I switch to BaseObservable instead?

Comment: Otherwise I've added more information to the bottom of my question. Please check.

Comment: Could you show the code where you are updating quantity field? The ViewModel, or Model.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I've managed to solved the problem myself and I've just posted my solution as an answer. Thanks for dropping by.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to overthink things. Calling `notifyItemChanged(position)` on the adapter instance is the missing piece. So it becomes a matter of how to pass the index of the RecyclerView item back to the adapter.

Edit `rv_item.xml` to take an additional variable, `position`:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.mycodez.Item"/>

    <!-- add this variable -->
    <variable
        name="position"
        type="int"/>

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.mycodez.ListViewModel" />
</data>
```

Also, in that same XML file, pass `position` to the `vm` methods triggered by `onClick`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/decrease_quantity"
    android:onClick="@{() -> vm.decrementItemQuantity(item, position)}"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/increase_quantity"
    android:onClick="@{() -> vm.incrementItemQuantity(item, position)}"/>
```

Then the `bind` method in the `ListRvAdapter` `ViewHolder` becomes:

```
public void bind(Item item, int position) { // new argument
    binding.setItem(item);
    binding.setPosition(position); // pass position to the layout
    binding.setVm(viewModel);
    binding.executePendingBindings();
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner);
}
```

Pass the new argument in the adapter's `onBindViewHolder` like so:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), position);
}
```

Finally, add two methods to the `ListRvAdapter` for respectively increasing and decreasing quantity:

```
public void increaseQuantity(int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);
    item.quantity += 1;
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void decreaseQuantity(int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);
    item.quantity -= 1;
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

With all that in place, when the Button `@+id/increase_quantity` is clicked, `vm.incrementItemQuantity(item, position)` is triggered. In a MVVM setup, the ViewModel will have a LiveData Event object for `position`:

```
public MutableLiveData<Event<Integer>> itemQuantityIncreased = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

And the call to `vm.incrementItemQuantity(item, position)` will set that object's value:

`itemQuantityIncreased.setValue(new Event<>(position))`;

Finally, the View will have an Observer on the ViewModel's `itemQuantityIncreased` LiveData object. Because the Event sends the RecyclerView item's position with it,   the View can get a hold of that and call `adapter.increaseQuantity(position)` where it's appropriate. `adapter.decreaseQuantity(position)` works just the same.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive comment. Is there really no simpler way to do it directly from within viewholder without involving listadapter?

Comment: Above solution is apt ,but I have different scenario like instead of upvote and down vote ,there is view count which I am getting from api and plus I don't want to notify whole item at that position I just want to update view count text ,How to achieve that ?